# Special symbol used for the derived set

Tags: symbols, mathematics

my lecturer has been using what seems to be an uncommon symbol that looks like a D for the derived set (Maths topology unit), so it's nearly impossible for me to find what its name is.

Would anyone be able to let me know what the name for this symbol is (and what its called in TeX)?

Image:

[image]

Comment: `$\mathcal{D}$`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome!